# C# COM Exception while opening an Excel File

Tags: c#, excel

I had developed a C# Desktop Application. My software does some Report Generation in Excel.  It was working fine so far in my client system. Recently, he upgraded to Microsoft Office 2013.

I noticed that Whenever he opens that Excel, it prompts the Activation wizard and does not allow report generation and throws an COM exception :

"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472"

Any idea, if it is possible at all, to handle it in the C# program and continue with report generation.

P.S : Please suggest only technical solution for the issue. I have already suggested the client to buy the license( if he hasn't) for the software for it to work.

Thanks

Comment: so... you want to use something that noone want to pay for...
you can hack Excel, but jail sucks :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you send text messages with your phone if you don't have a contract? No, same problem as yours.

A **valid license** is needed to use Excel, if he doesn't want to pay generate your reports for **Open-Source alternatives**.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a Time-out exception.
Excel Interop does not return untill excel is fully loaded...
because there is the Dialog box blocking Excel startup, a Timeout exception is thrown.

if it is Your Computer, just activate your Excel copy.

if it is on your client's, you should require a valid Excel installation (means activated)

Alternativly, there are some Free solutions for that such as :
 1. Generating CSV files (though no styling is possible)
 2. Generate Xls through ADO (again, no styling)
 3. Use Open Office (but will require the client to have it too)
 4. Use 3ed Party Libraries like : https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/
    or commercial packages from CompnentOne Etc...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use the primary interop assemblies for Office, to automate Office without actually having the applications or license, but **I am not a solicitor or licensing expert of any kind, just some guy on the internet, who could be completely wrong**!!

Once your program has automated the report, your client could then use [Excel viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=10) to view the report.

You can download the PIA's from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=3508).